# how to write url in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to add '-' or '+' in between words in url. For example url like:

```
http://localhost/bollywood/details/23-abhishek-back-from-dubai-holiday.htm
```

My Route Pattern is

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AddExtension",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{title}.htm",
            defaults: new { controller = "Bollywood", action = "Details" }
        );
```

I am creating a link like this on my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.n_headline, "Details", new { id = item.News_ID, title = item.n_headline.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

My Bollywood controller is here

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string controller, string action, string title)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        tblBollywood tblbolly = db.tblBollywood.Find(id);
        if (tblbollywood == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tblbollywood);
    }
```

Comment: What does the current url looks like? What is the content of `item.heading` and how is it generated?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this method ;

```
public static string ToSeoUrl(this string url)
{
    // make the url lowercase
    string encodedUrl = (url ?? "").ToLower();

    // replace & with and
    encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"\&+", "and");

    // remove characters
    encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Replace("'", "");

    // remove invalid characters
    encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"[^a-z0-9-\u0600-\u06FF]", "-");

    // remove duplicates
    encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"-+", "-");

    // trim leading & trailing characters
    encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Trim('-');

    return encodedUrl;
}
```

then you can use this way :

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, actionName: "Category", controllerName: "Product", routeValues: new { Id = item.Id, productName = item.Name.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

**Edit :**

you need to create a new custom route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Page",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}-{pagename}.htm",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
);
```

then use ActionLink this way :

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", actionName: "Contact", controllerName: "Home", routeValues: new { Id = item.id, pagename = item.heading.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Comment: where I have to add this function either in controller class or else any where ?

Comment: you can create a class called helper in your application.

Comment: How do i call the Html Helper method from my controller method? Simply using the static class HtmlHelper does not work.

Comment: you should use your helper class in your view not controller.

Comment: Thank you its working..but by doing that I get another problem "The request for page is bad request" and I am searching a record by ID not pagename then also I get the same problem

Comment: @Html.ActionLink(item.n_headline, "Details", new { id = item.News_ID, title = Html.ToSeoUrl(item.n_headline) }, htmlAttributes: null) its not working but if i simpley pass (item.n_headline) to that actionlink then the requested page is shown

Comment: By doing this its working '-' is added to url but by doing that the ID parameter goes null

Comment: did you set `Id = item.Id` ?

Comment: yes sir..and when I click on that link url is shown in correct format that same I want but the requested page is not shown and the error is..ID parameter has null value

Comment: Is it necessary to make some changes in web.config file ??

Comment: no, just make sure that having Id in your action method as parameter.

Comment: Look this one is my actionLink @Html.ActionLink(item.n_headline, "Details", new { id = item.News_ID, title = item.n_headline.ToSeoUrl() }, htmlAttributes: null)

Comment: I think that if we are putting '-' or '+' in urls then IIS server do not redirect to a requested page

Comment: I tested my answer, there is no problem.